# Using Laravel Dusk with Doctrine

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel with Doctrine. I want to use Dusk for browser testing, but I noticed for example the `login` function in `UserController` uses Eloquent model functions to retrieve the model for authentication. 
Is there any known possibility to use Dusk with Doctrine? Or is there any other browser test framework for Laravel using Doctrine?

Comment: Did you try it? If you did, what happened? If not, get to it!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried and got an error because Dusk tries to use the where or find function of an eloquent model on a doctrine entity model.

Comment: Looks like Dusk doesn't support Doctrine entities then!